# Backbone.js + Rails 3 urls and collections with nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, routes, has-and-belongs-to-many, nested-routes

I'm trying to create a new application with both Rails and Backbone.js, but there are quite a few nested relations that are making it rather difficult.

On the Rails side, I'm using a HABTM relationship between Ingredients and Allergens. I'm trying to access the ingredients that are associated with an array of allergens. The plan was to query the Allergens table with the array, get their ids, then query that against the AllergensIngredients table to get the Ingredients ids.

The routes are nested as such:

```
  resources :ingredients do
    resources :allergens
  end
```

With the url as '/ingredients/:ingredient_id/allergens'. It works wonderfully for Rails. On the Backbone side I've tried using Collections to fetch the Allergens with the url '/allergens', but that is rejected according to my Rails routes (route '/allergens' does not exist). So, I added a standalone `resources :allergens` route underneath my nested routes. That created a recognizable route for Backbone, but issues still remained with my Rails allergens_controller.rb:

```
  class AllergensController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :json
    def index
      respond_with(
        @ingredient ||= Ingredient.find(params[:ingredient_id]),
        @allergens = @ingredient.allergens,
      )
    end
  # ...
  end
```

because @ingredient cannot be found without an id. I've tried using Backbone.sync and $.get, but those still require a url, which ultimately goes through the rails controller. How can I use Backbone to just query a single table in the database, without any interference from Rails or urls? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work taking a different approach. I created a new action in the allergens_controller that just returned Allergen.all, then used an AJAX get request in Backbone to return the xhr object. Not an elegant fix, but a fix nonetheless!